# Django. Edit model form in popup in admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there any ready apps for django admin, that allows to edit model in popup?

I want next functionallity:

- View edit form for model in popup.
- On model save - update row in list of models.

Motivation: reduce page reloads.

Also, if there any solutions oriented on massive manual data updates for django? I've taken a look at django grappelli - it improves view of data, but edit data is still not usable.

P.S.: If such kind of app is not available - I'll start open source project.

Comment: I doubt it - ["the admin is not your app"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/677509/16361). You can always write your own CRUD interface that has popups, but the admin is deliberately simplistic in many ways, and there's no current mechanism for in-place updates to model listings - that would be a pretty major change in how it works.

Comment: "The admin is not your app" isn't quite saying what you think it is and in many cases I think it's poor advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to open a popup, simply create a link to your 'add' view with the following attribute on that link `onclick='return showAddAnotherPopup(this);'`

Comment: Neat trick!  Do you know if there is a way to close the popup on save?

Answer (score 0):

You can do most of what you ask there (at least point 1 and 2) using the django built in admin customisations.

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/

The django admin itself already uses some things similar to this, pay special attention to the django _popup=1 variable in the request URI.

You will have to add a custom modelname_change_list.html file to provide some javascript and in the ModelAdmin override the delet_view, change_view, response_add and potentially response_change.