# Django Admin, can't groupe by: Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, django-queryset

I have this model which maps to a postgresql view

```
class AppModel(models.Model):

    nbr = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.ForeignKey(AppWilaya,blank=True, null=True)
    date_preorder = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,blank=True, db_column='dummy_id')
```

What I want to achieve is to sum **"nbr"** by **"region"**, so:

```
class AppModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
....
def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AppModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)  
        qs=qs.values("region").annotate(total=Sum( 'nbr'))
```

But Django Admin seems not accepting **.values("region")** as an exception is thrown:

```
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
Exception Location: [PATH_TO]\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\util.py in lookup_field, line 242
```

Comment: I suspected a bug behind this exception, which was not accepted https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you are using Django 1.6, which changed the use of `queryset` to `get_queryset`. So to prevent any confusion, just use `get_queryset` or use a different name altogether if this is not what you intend.

The `get_queryset` method in ModelAdmin has the following description in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) (emphasis mine):

> The get_queryset method on a ModelAdmin returns a QuerySet of all **model instances** that can be edited by the admin site.

Your implementation of `queryset` returns a projection, which is *not* a model (something containing `_meta`), but a dictionary, hence the exception.

It is therefore not a problem with your query in itself, but a problem of where you use it. The `get_queryset` method is not the right place to do what you want.

If you want to use this information for filtering, have a look at [creating a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). If you want to show this information as one of the fields in your changelist, [use a callable in `list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

Comment: if _get_queryset method is not the right place_ , then how is it possible to to display grouped data that leverage filters features in the admin list ?

Comment: you can't use _callable_ to achieve _aggregation_ on a set of model instances.

Comment: Not for arbitrary sets, no. If you want your aggregation to be done over (e.g.) the current change-list selection, I'm afraid you'll have to look at extending the admin templates and calling custom methods from there. Remember: the admin is not your app! http://stackoverflow.com/a/677509/1636314